# Get all dialogs in a QuickBlox application?

Tags: quickblox, quickblox-android

Every one hour, our server has to notify all the users who haven't read the messages. 
Can we do that with QuickBlox? We have the credentials of all users stored. So, we can login with each user and get his dialogs and check if there are any unread messages but that's a very long process. We can't login with each user. Is there any way we can get list of dialogs from the application level?

Comment: Hi Uttam, Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: @KAR We had to go with the approach mentioned in the question. It was not an good way but QB doesn't give any better option!